# Log every unique visit of an user without JSESSIONID

Tags: spring, logging, spring-security

I am trying to log a unique identifier to my application logs that will distinctly track every visit of an user in a Spring MVC application. The intent is to store this identifier in a cookie and grep for logs that match the identifier. When QA or Customer Support run into issues with the app, they will provide the value of the identifier from cookie and can be used by the application dev team to search and troubleshoot.

I do not want to use JSESSIONID as it can be hijacked. I am currently logging timestamp and user id but that does not help when an user can simultaneously login from more than one browser.

Does Spring provide any feature to support this? If not, is there a way to still use JSESSIONID but prevent Session hijacking?

Comment: You do not want to suppress that a user can have more than one session? SS would give you that for almost free. I don't really understand your setup. You using user ID implies there's some sort of authentication in place. Hence, jsessionid is used anyway?

Comment: I have a WebSeal authentication using sha certificates. Basically, the issue is if I centrally log all the session ids in a log file, someone who has access to the log and the application might mis use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the session ID (jsessionid) and hash it using SHA-1 or similar. By theory a hash is irreversible but unique given the input is unique.

We use a `ServletFilter` that stores this value in an MDC (slf4j/log4j) which then allows us to use that value in the log pattern. Example: http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/11/log4j-mdc-mapped-diagnostic-context-example-code/

Comment: Thanks @Marcel. I was infact using a servlet filter/MDC to capture session id. I can try to hash it or I also read that an UUID can be randomly generated. Thanks for your suggestion.